# Can I compile datasets so the original database won´t be needed? [c#, .net framework]

Tags: c#, sql-server, compilation, dataset, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to compile datasets before deploying, so I won´t need to have the original database? (These are read-only operations, so there will be no changes done to the database after compilation.)

//Reason for this. I´ve made simple a app that gets its data from local MSSQL database. The problem is that it needs MSSQL on machines where it´s deployed (as portable) which is inconvenient. Yes, I could´ve done it differently but I wanted to practice databases and I might have futher use for this knowledge.

Comment: if you mean `System.DataSet` (which *probably* isn't a good thing to use in most cases... it is kinda a legacy API that was intended for people migrating from the old pre-.NET ADO recordset API), then: you can serialize (`XmlSerializer`) a `DataSet`, and deserialize it where needed; that work?

Comment: Can't understand what you trying to achieve. If you need distribute your application with some preloaded data then you can use binary/json/sqlite files distributed within your application.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think I do. Unfortunately it´s the first thing that come up from "how to fill combobox form database" search. But serializing/deserializing might be a solution.

Comment: @picolino It´s my free time project. Loosely tied to school. I wanted to play around with databases. Concidering it "worked on my machine" I realized later when distributing to friends that not many people have MSSQL server intalled.

Comment: @krysta24, as a simple solution try to use [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) database instead of MSSQL. It's fully cross-platform and portable. This is not an answer on your question but useful advise ;)

Comment: @krysta24 there is (edit: was) also SQL Server Compact Edition; it is essentially just binaries that you ship *with* your app and which runs in-process - it isn't a separate install; any use? (basically: much like the sqlite comment above, but without the need to change any of your syntax)

Comment: Compact edition is deprecated - not advisable to start learning/using that.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, this might be it. I´ll try it.

Comment: oh (krysta24) - I'm going to defer to @SMor there; if it is dead, it is dead :(

Comment: Thanks guys anyway. I guess I´ll go in serialization way I´ve used JSON.net before so it shouldn´t be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Manually transfer your data out of the database and into an `app.config` file that the application reads.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am sorry you don't like it, but I provided it in an attempt to answer the OP's question. In what way does it not satisfy?

Comment: in what way *does it* satisfy? yes, technically you can brute force application data into app.config; that doesn't make it a good approach, or even a viable one in .NET Core, let alone the "manual" part, and the fact that it doesn't even begin to discuss how to load the data; virtually *any other way* of transferring/encapsulating data would be preferable, frankly

Answer (score 0):

Use the "SQL Server Compact Power Tools" extension to migrate a SQL Server database (with data) to SQL Server Compact, and include the SQL CE database (and required runtime DLL files) with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Solution has been just ditching whole database and serializing data for release.